# Accessing Textbox in MainWindow from another widget

Tags: c++, widget, qt5

I created a Qt5 UI-Application in QtCreator. It consists of a MainWindow with a PlainTextEdit and a custom widget called "Canvas" that is used for drawing stuff. Now, the PlainTextEdit is set to read-only and should be used as a log window for some status messages that might occur in the canvas widget. For this I created a "log" method in MainWindow that just appends some text to the PlainTextEdit.

However, I simply cannot find a way to access the textfield from within the canvas widget. I tried to get the parent widget of Canvas but failed somehow. I tried turning the MainWindow class into a singleton and get the instance of it, but that does not seem to work either.

So any tips on how you would go about creating a log window, that is usable globally from all widgets?

Comment: "failed somehow", "does not seem to work" are pretty vague descriptions of what went wrong for you. Could you be more specific? Regarding the singleton: store 'this' when you run your MainWindow constructor and let everything else work as usual (i.e make sure you don't 'accidentally' create a second instance of MainWindow).

Comment: Have you thought of storing the text of the `PlainTextEdit` in another `static` member? That way you can get the text without an instance of the `MainWindow`. Another option is to make the `MainWindow` class the parent of the `Canvas` widget. There are many ways to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would it be easier to just add a [signal](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) to your custom widget and connect it to the [PlainTextEdit slot](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qplaintextedit.html#appendPlainText)?